# JQuery cookie use items in array to insert html list items?

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, insert, arraylist

I am looking to insert html (listItems) at a div layer with id "LogInsert" using JQuery which accesses a cookie (LogSum) containing an array of key/value pairs.  Some of the items out of the array cookie need to be combined with the inserted html into the DOM.

I have the following function script that errors, which is called on various events:

```
      function SetLogSum() {
      var listItems = "";
      var Cooksplit = $.cookie('logSum').split(',');

      $.each(Cooksplit, function(key, val) {
      listItems += "<div class='loggedinDetail'>" +
        "<div class='loggedinImage'>" +
        "<img src=" + val.uPic + " alt=" + val.uFName + val.uLName + " /></div>" +
        "<div class='loggedinName'><span>" + val.uFName + "</span></div>" +
        "<div class='loggedinStatus'><span>" + val.uGroup + " • " + val.uContRev + "</span></div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='loggedinHistory'>" +
        "<div class='loggedinReviewCount' title='Reviews'><span>" + val.CntRev + " Reviews</span></div>" +
        "<div class='loggedinTripCount' title=''><span>" + val.CntBook + "</span></div>" +
        "</div>";
    }
    );
    $("#LogInsert").html(listItems);
    }
```

The logSum cookie holds information such as:

```
uPic=avatar-male&uContRev=Contributor&uName=thedon&uGroup=Admin&uOP=0&uOA=0&uOH=0&uOI=0&uV=1&uP=0&uRv=0&uF=0&uCb=1&uPEC=0&uS=0&uC=UK&uL=en-US&uFName=Martin&uLName=Sansone&CntRev=6&CntBook=2
```

I know that the listItems part works and the .html insert as I use the same structure regularly in AJAX calls. So my problem is how Im handling the cookie but I don't know why. Any ideas ?

Comment: You are splitting the cookie on a comma, but the cookie text you showed us contain zero commas?

Comment: @AndersHolmström: I believe, based on the code, that that's *one* of the values from the cookie, not the cookie as a whole.

Comment: yes, you have all been a great help.. I've clearly been awake far too long and suffering brain fade.  Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert:

```
valueStr = "uPic=avatar-male&uContRev=Contributor&uName=thedon&uGroup=Admin&uOP=0&uOA=0&uOH=0&uOI=0&uV=1&uP=0&uRv=0&uF=0&uCb=1&uPEC=0&uS=0&uC=UK&uL=en-US&uFName=Martin&uLName=Sansone&CntRev=6&CntBook=2"
```

string to an Object, where keys are `uPic`,`uContRev`,`uName`, etc... and values are `avatar-male`,`Contributor`,`thedon`, etc... like this:

```
var val = JSON.parse( '{"'+
                          valueStr.replace(/=/g,'":"')
                          .replace(/&/g,'","') + 
                       '"}');
```

then do like this:

```
listItems += "<div class='loggedinDetail'>" +
    "<div class='loggedinImage'>" +
    "<img src=" + val.uPic + " alt=" + val.uFName + val.uLName + " /></div>" +
    "<div class='loggedinName'><span>" + val.uFName + "</span></div>" +
    "<div class='loggedinStatus'><span>" + val.uGroup + " • " + val.uContRev + "</span></div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div class='loggedinHistory'>" +
    "<div class='loggedinReviewCount' title='Reviews'><span>" + val.CntRev + " Reviews</span></div>" +
    "<div class='loggedinTripCount' title=''><span>" + val.CntBook + "</span></div>" +
    "</div>";
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/N4ad5/)

Comment: Thank you Engineer, this solution fits well with all of my other JSON AJAX and appreciate you pointing out that I needed to parse the cookie string back.  The cookie was originally generated from server side using JSON in the first place!  doh..  clean and tidy, worked like a dream.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, `val` will be a string, not an object, but you're treating it as an object. You'll have to split each `val` on the `&` character, and then each of *those* pieces on the `=` character, ending up with the key and value. Then use those to construct your HTML fragment.

If you walk through with a debugger (there's [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) for not using client-side debuggers in 2012 :-) ), this should be fairly clear when inspecting `val`.

Here's a *sketch* of how that might look, neither debugged nor guaranteed, but it should get you going the right way:

```
$.each(Cooksplit, function(key, valStr) {
    var items = valStr.split("&"),
        val = {};

    // Build up an object in `val` using the keys and
    // values from this entry
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var parts = item.split("=");
        val[parts[0]] = parts[1];
    });

    // ...use `val` as you were...
    listItems += /* ... */;
});
```

There I use an inner loop to build up an object in `val` with the keys and values from the string, so your HTML fragment building code can be largely unchanged.

Comment: Thank you T.J. I had got Firebug open and have no excuses... :)